# How to provide a negative condition in Case/When clause while using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.8. I am making a conditional aggregate where a `Case` statement inside `Sum` looks like this:

```
Sum(Case(When(x='ABC', then=F('some_field')), default=0))
```

If I want to say x should be anything but not 'ABC' then how do I negate this condition. Will `~Q` work in this scenario ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. "Not equal" conditions can be created using `Q` objects:

```
Sum(Case(When(~Q(x='ABC'), then=F('some_field')), default=0))
```

Comment: So I tried saving this expression in a variable to reuse it at multiple places. Apparently I get error like 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression' when I use it with aggregate. 

However with a regular annotate it works just fine. Any idea what am I doing wrong here ?